# Python send packet over 443

Tags: python

I have looked and perhaps i missed it. I currently have a file such as the one below:

```
PUT /URL/TO/SEND/REQUEST
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
...

bunch of data here
```

This file contains the header & the data i want to send over ssl. I know on windows i can use fiddler etc.. to send this raw data BUT i was hoping to use python. I tried looking (may be not hard enough) at urllib2 urllib & httplib to see if i could just send this file as the entire request i don't want to deal with parsing the file etc... Is this possible?

I did notice that in httplib i can use `request` where "body can be a file object." but from the description seems as though it still sends the header seperately and that file is only for the data being sent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't documented, but it looks like you should be able to use `httplib.HTTPConnection.send()` for this:

```
In [13]: httplib.HTTPConnection.send??
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<unbound method HTTPConnection.send>
File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py
Definition: httplib.HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
Source:
    def send(self, data):
        """Send `data' to the server."""
        if self.sock is None:
            if self.auto_open:
                self.connect()
            else:
                raise NotConnected()

        if self.debuglevel > 0:
            print "send:", repr(data)
        blocksize = 8192
        if hasattr(data,'read') and not isinstance(data, array):
            if self.debuglevel > 0: print "sendIng a read()able"
            datablock = data.read(blocksize)
            while datablock:
                self.sock.sendall(datablock)
                datablock = data.read(blocksize)
        else:
            self.sock.sendall(data)
```

The `request()` method combines the header and body and passes it to this function, which looks like it should handle strings or file objects.

Of course you will still need to know the host so that you can create the `HTTPConnection` object, so your code might look something like this (untested):

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1')
conn.send(open(filename))
response = conn.getresponse()
```

**edit:** It turns out there is some internal state stuff that keeps this from working as is, here is a workaround (full example with google main page), but it is a bit of a hack.  Tested using Python 2.6 and 2.7, does not appear to work on 3.x by just replacing `httplib` with `http.client`:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google.com')
conn.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n')
conn._HTTPConnection__state = httplib._CS_REQ_SENT
response = conn.getresponse()
```

The key part here is setting `conn.__state` (mangled name) to the `httplib._CS_REQ_SENT` after calling `send()`.

Comment: thanks for the help! i also found this which talks about the exception that is raised due to using it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385281/responsenotready-for-really-simple-python-http-request

Comment: This link talks about how to use socket module + ssl: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

Comment: You should probably add that as an answer, if it is what you will actually be using.

Comment: thanks F.J that work around works i would rather do that then have to implement the ssl socket module. Thanks!